# loop reseting in scrollview (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uiscrollview, xib

My code is a uiscrolview with two pages and a button. The problem is that if I am on the view controller info (middle image). Then hit the button to go back to scrollview it goes back to page 1. So no matter what going from the info slide to the scrollview it always goes back to view controller 1 and the loop resets. If I am on vc 2 hit the info button go to the info slide.If I hit the button on the info slide I want to return to vc 2. My code is below. Essentially the loop always resets I want to fix that if possible.

[image: page one]

[image]

[image]

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet var slideScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slideScrollView.delegate = self


    let slides:[slide] = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)



}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

func createSlides() -> [slide]{
    let slide1:slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! slide
    slide1.label.text = "1"






    let slide2:slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! slide
    slide2.label.text = "2"






    return [slide1,slide2 ]
}

func setupSlideScrollView(slides:[slide]) {
    slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    slideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)

    for i in 0..<slides.count{
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        slideScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

}}
```

Comment: What's the point of inserting three large images in size between text and lines of code?  Do you really need to have people see them in that size?

Comment: Add the code of button action of info controller.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewWillAppear` problem , check if you are setting anything in those functions.

Comment: I don't understand how that will help.

Comment: when you go back to the viewController that contains the scrollView , those two functions will be called automatically if you implemented them, so if you made any scrollView code in any of them it will be recalled when you go back

Comment: yeah I think the easiest thing to do will be to use nslayout constraints and use them to expand the info slide. That way I am not going changing view controllers.